# Android Talkback Google Chrome scroll issue

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, accessibility, talkback

Fiddle here: https://jsbin.com/gijixa/

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Talkback is on.
2. There is a `<div></div>` with its own scroll area.
3. There is a list of accessible elements in the div.
4. User selects the first element on the list.
5. User scrolls (may be accidentally) with two fingers.
6. User double taps to select his item.

**Expected scenario**

The first item is selected.

**Current scenario**

When the div scrolls, the talkback indicator is fixed to its position within the viewport. Lets say the div scrolls by two item. Now, the talkback indicator is floating over the third item. When user double taps, third item is selected.

This seems like a bug because the user is never made aware of the third item being selected. The last spoken item is the first item.

This happens only if scrolling on a div with overflow scroll. Normal scrolling in the viewport itself does not have this problem.

Can anyone please direct me to the correct person or place where I can report this bug or get an explanation why this is happening?

Or, does anyone have a workaround to squash this bug?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can report issues related to google talkback maybe by below link:
   https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/issues/
2. Users can define scrolling gestures by this way on Android 4.4.2 or above and google talkback ver.4.2 or above:
   `settings/accessibility/vision/talkback/settings/manage gestures/LscrollK`
   in newer above android l, talkback maybe named in menus by 'voice assistant'.